# SQL search for all the projects which have all mentioned tags assigned

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query for searching projects based on tags. It's working fine if any of the tag is matching.

```
SELECT * 
FROM projects 
WHERE projects.id IN (SELECT taggable_id 
                      FROM taggings 
                      WHERE taggable_type='Project' 
                        AND taggable_id=projects.id 
                        AND taggings.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3))
```

There are three tables, `Taggings` with columns `id, taggable_id, taggable_type, tag_id`; `Tags` with columns `id, name`; and `Projects` with columns `id, name, description`.

What I want is, to search for all the projects for which all 3 tags are assigned.

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of matches.  Your subquery is redundant in the comparison to `p.id` (done both by the `IN` and by the correlation clause).  Here is one method:

```
SELECT p.*
from projects p
WHERE 3 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM taggings t
           WHERE t.taggable_type = 'Project' AND
                 t.taggable_id = p.id AND
                 t.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3)
          );
```

You can also do this using `IN`:

```
SELECT p.*
from projects p
WHERE p.id = (SELECT t.taggable_id
              FROM taggings t
              WHERE t.taggable_type = 'Project' AND
                    t.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3)
              GROUP BY t.taggable_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
             );
```